# Learning Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

Ok I am wanting to learn how a OS kernel works and was wanting to read over the Linux kernel code. However, Ive never don't this kind of thing before and was wondering if there was specific way I should go through the code.. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would start with [kernelnewbies](http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelHacking) or for a very simple intro [learning linux kernel](http://www.learninglinuxkernel.com/)

That is if you want to specifically know the Linux kernel. But after 20years the Linux kernel is now a very large and complex project and so probably isn't the best intro to how a simple Unix kernel works

There is a very interesting project to implement a [kernel in python](https://launchpad.net/pycorn) which is probably an easier start if you simply want to know how **a** kernel works

ps If you prefer paper there is an [O'Reilly book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596005658.do) - it's a little dated but does cover the 2.6 kernel. I haven't read this edition so I don't know how good it is.

Comment: Thanks.. I tried to type in a few combos of words to find stuff like this but couldn't find relevant material through google on first 7 pages no matter query i typed in. lol